# How to make items stack on mobile view

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have made 3 images side by side using display flex in desktop screen but now i want to make them responsive and make the items stack in mobile mode. Can someone tell me how to do it?

Code:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 10%;
}

.column img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.column p {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.partners-h1 p {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  font-size-adjust: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.partners-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* added for demonstration purpose by editor */
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/sneak.jpg">
    <p>Sneak Energy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/kontrol.png">
    <p>Kontrol Freek</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/astro.jpg">
    <p>Astro Gaming</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a media queries to change the `flext-direction: row;` to `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Comment: You can try to use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can think of, towards solving this.

**Method 1: Using Media query**

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column; /* Initially, mobile first */
}

/* If minimum screen width is 320, switch to side by side. Replace 320 with whatever screen size you want to swap between horizontal and stacked view */
@media (min-width:320px)
{
  .row {
    flex-direction:row;
  }
}

.column {
  padding: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 10%;
}

.column img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.column p {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.partners-h1 p {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  font-size-adjust: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.partners-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/* added for demonstration purpose by editor */
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/sneak.jpg">
    <p>Sneak Energy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/kontrol.png">
    <p>Kontrol Freek</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/astro.jpg">
    <p>Astro Gaming</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method 2: Using flex-wrap to automatically stack when 2 images don't fit side to side**

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.column {
  padding: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 10%;
}

.column img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.column p {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.partners-h1 p {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  font-size-adjust: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.partners-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/* added for demonstration purpose by editor */
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/sneak.jpg">
    <p>Sneak Energy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/kontrol.png">
    <p>Kontrol Freek</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/astro.jpg">
    <p>Astro Gaming</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a media query to address screens up to a certain width like:

```
@media only screen 
  and (max-width: 800px) { 
    selector { 
      property: value;
    } 
}
```

then change the `flex-direction` property from the default `row` to `column`:
`flex-direction: column;`

Reference to media queries: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen
  and (max-width: 800px) {
    .row {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.column {
  padding: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 10%;
}

.column img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.column p {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.partners-h1 p {
  font-family: "BatmanForeverAlternate";
  font-size-adjust: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.partners-h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* added for demonstration purpose by editor */
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/sneak.jpg">
    <p>Sneak Energy</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/kontrol.png">
    <p>Kontrol Freek</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/astro.jpg">
    <p>Astro Gaming</p>
  </div>
</div>
```